# Does Warwick's ult cancel Fiora's ult if timed correctly?

Tags: league-of-legends

Can Warwick stop Fiora's ultimate by using his ultimate at the same time as Fiora activates hers?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if timed correctly Warwick can suppress Fiora during her ultimate.